# failed Building static HTML for pages - Gatsby and p5js

Tags: gatsby, github-pages, p5.js

Site: https://github.com/GiorgioMartini/thisisgiorgioweb

Getting this error when deploying to github pages:

`failed Building static HTML for pages`

I am using `"react-p5": "^1.3.6"`

Before I had the error: `window is not defined` so they suggested i add this

`gatsby-node.js`

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
  if (stage === 'build-html' || stage === 'develop-html') {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /p5/,
            use: 'null-loader'
          }
        ]
      }
    });
  }
};
```

But now i get the error: `failed Building static HTML for page` and further below:

`Error: Minified React error #130; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args[]=object&args[]= for the full message or use the non-minified dev environmen  t for full errors and additional helpful warnings.`

My sketch is used as a background one index:

```
const Background = (props) => {
  ...
  const windowResized = (p5) => p5.resizeCanvas(p5.windowWidth, p5.windowHeight)
  ...

  const setup = (p5, canvasParentRef) => {
    canvas = p5.createCanvas(p5.windowWidth, p5.windowHeight).parent(canvasParentRef)
    const colWidth = (p5.width / cols)
    const colHeight = (p5.height / rows)
    canvas.position(0, 0)
    canvas.style('z-index', '-1')
    p5.background(0);
    for (let x = 0; x < cols+1; x++) {
      for (let y = 0; y < rows+1; y++) {
        spots.push(Spot(p5, x * colWidth, y * colHeight))
      }
    }
  }

  const draw = (p5) => {
    p5.background(0)
    ...
    })

  };
  return <Sketch windowResized={windowResized} setup={setup} draw={draw} />
}
```

Any idea on what might be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal of adding a custom `onCreateWebpackConfig` function is to modify the webpack's configuration to avoid the transpilation of some `node_modules` folder by adding a `null` loader, so the testing name must match (it's a regular expression) to a folder inside `node_modules`. In your case, should be `react-p5` instead of `p5`.

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
  if (stage === 'build-html' || stage === 'develop-html') {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /react-p5/,
            use: 'null-loader'
          }
        ]
      }
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove all of your lazy import from your project

```
const Component = React.lazy(() => import("../Common/component"))
```

Remove it
Also you need to remove Suspense

```
<Suspense fallback={<Loader />}></Suspense>
```

This will solve your issue.

N.B: Gatsby doesn't need any lazy loading